# How to capture transaction id in magento 1.9 admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, transactional-mail

I have problem in show Transaction ID to admin ( refer the image ), how can we store the transaction table in database. I'm new to magento.

I have searched for solution but haven't got success.

Please give me right solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use below code to add trasaction:**

```
$transaction = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment_transaction');
$transaction->setParentId($parentId); // this is parent trasaction Id if any
$transaction->setOrderId(1); // this is order Id
$transaction->setTxntId($txnId); // this is trasaction Id
$transaction->setTxnType($txnType); // authorise or capture or both
$transaction->setIsClosed(true);
$transaction->setAdditionalInformation($arrayofdata);
try {
        $transaction->save();
    } 
catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Prasanta.. is this is the correct path to insert the your suggested code? '/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment/Transaction.php'. kindly guide me.

Comment: You can add from anywhere by providing the specified values. Better to create a singleton model and write a method by passing the required data and call that model from success action.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer